# How to pass dynamically component instance?

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular, so can you help me with the following problem:
I'm using a popover library and I need to pass an instance dynamically to open popover.
I set the name as [mdePopoverTriggerFor] and then I need to pass the string value(indicator.value) to mde-popover(component) as name of instance (#indicator.value)

```
<div *ngFor="let indicator of sortByScore(mergedIndicators)" class="indicator indicator-text">
                            {{translations.static[indicator.indicatorCode]}}
                                <!--*** TRIGGER FOR OPENING **-->
                                <i 
                                    *ngIf="indicator.tags.length>0" 
                                    class="fas fa-comment-alt"
                                    <!--** here I assign the name for instance -->
                                    [mdePopoverTriggerFor]="indicator.value"
                                    mdePopoverTriggerOn="click"></i>


                                <!--** POPOVER  -->
                                <mde-popover #indicator.value="mdePopover" [mdePopoverOverlapTrigger]="false">
                                    <mat-card style="max-width: 300px">

                                        <mat-card-title>Tip</mat-card-title>
                                        <mat-card-content>
                                            Numerical representation of the threat level in meta-percentage value (could exceed 100%), if more than the danger threshold (85% by default) - is considered malicious (highlighted in red). The threshold is set by the tLab administrator.
                                        </mat-card-content>
                                    </mat-card>
                                </mde-popover>

                            </div>
```

Comment: the `#indicator` is a variable and you can retrieve this in your component by adding the property `@ViewChild('indicator') indicator`

Comment: This is not my component, its library's one

Comment: But this part of HTML is part of your own component right? If that's the case, you need that one